Stopping a @keyframes animation at specific keyframe
I have a simple CSS keyframes animation (from https://codepen.io/hopefulcodegirl/pen/WNwmOQX) - I was wondering if there is a way to stop the animation at a specific keyframe (this would be based on data I get from backend) - so that the progress bar stops at some give percentage. The only way I can think of is generating CSS files on first website render with different keyframes defined inside, depending on the target percent value. But this hardly seems like an efficient method. Is my only option to just redo the animation in JS?


.color-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: background_load 5s infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  /*margin: 280px auto;*/
  /*padding: 20px 40px;*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.Loading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loading:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  animation: load 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes load {
0.0% {
 width: 0.0%;
 background: #94e02d;
}
2.04% {
 width: 2.04%;
 background: #96e02c;
}
4.08% {
 width: 4.08%;
 background: #98e12b;
}
6.12% {
 width: 6.12%;
 background: #9ae12a;
}
8.16% {
 width: 8.16%;
 background: #9ce229;
}
10.2% {
 width: 10.2%;
 background: #9ee328;
}
12.24% {
 width: 12.24%;
 background: #a1e327;
}
14.29% {
 width: 14.29%;
 background: #a3e426;
}
16.33% {
 width: 16.33%;
 background: #a5e525;
}
18.37% {
 width: 18.37%;
 background: #a7e524;
}
20.41% {
 width: 20.41%;
 background: #a9e623;
}
22.45% {
 width: 22.45%;
 background: #ace622;
}
24.49% {
 width: 24.49%;
 background: #aee721;
}
26.53% {
 width: 26.53%;
 background: #b0e821;
}
28.57% {
 width: 28.57%;
 background: #b2e820;
}
30.61% {
 width: 30.61%;
 background: #b4e91f;
}
32.65% {
 width: 32.65%;
 background: #b6ea1e;
}
34.69% {
 width: 34.69%;
 background: #b9ea1d;
}
36.73% {
 width: 36.73%;
 background: #bbeb1c;
}
38.78% {
 width: 38.78%;
 background: #bdec1b;
}
40.82% {
 width: 40.82%;
 background: #bfec1a;
}
42.86% {
 width: 42.86%;
 background: #c1ed19;
}
44.9% {
 width: 44.9%;
 background: #c4ed18;
}
46.94% {
 width: 46.94%;
 background: #c6ee17;
}
48.98% {
 width: 48.98%;
 background: #c8ef16;
}
51.02% {
 width: 51.02%;
 background: #caef16;
}
53.06% {
 width: 53.06%;
 background: #ccf015;
}
55.1% {
 width: 55.1%;
 background: #cef114;
}
57.14% {
 width: 57.14%;
 background: #d1f113;
}
59.18% {
 width: 59.18%;
 background: #d3f212;
}
61.22% {
 width: 61.22%;
 background: #d5f211;
}
63.27% {
 width: 63.27%;
 background: #d7f310;
}
65.31% {
 width: 65.31%;
 background: #d9f40f;
}
67.35% {
 width: 67.35%;
 background: #dcf40e;
}
69.39% {
 width: 69.39%;
 background: #def50d;
}
71.43% {
 width: 71.43%;
 background: #e0f60c;
}
73.47% {
 width: 73.47%;
 background: #e2f60b;
}
75.51% {
 width: 75.51%;
 background: #e4f70b;
}
77.55% {
 width: 77.55%;
 background: #e6f80a;
}
79.59% {
 width: 79.59%;
 background: #e9f809;
}
81.63% {
 width: 81.63%;
 background: #ebf908;
}
83.67% {
 width: 83.67%;
 background: #edf907;
}
85.71% {
 width: 85.71%;
 background: #effa06;
}
87.76% {
 width: 87.76%;
 background: #f1fb05;
}
89.8% {
 width: 89.8%;
 background: #f4fb04;
}
91.84% {
 width: 91.84%;
 background: #f6fc03;
}
93.88% {
 width: 93.88%;
 background: #f8fd02;
}
95.92% {
 width: 95.92%;
 background: #fafd01;
}
97.96% {
 width: 97.96%;
 background: #fcfe00;
}
100.0% {
 width: 100.0%;
 background: #ffff00;
}
}
        <div class="color-container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="Loading"></div>
          </div>
        </div>




Stopping after a certain width can be done with CSS variables, but what do you want to happen to the color? Should it stick at the nearest color or should it go all the way to yellow?

@AHaworth I would want the color to stop at the same/similar value as width/percentage.

@Yogi I can't see how to use the value usiing only CSS as attr is not recognised by browsers in general in anything but the content property at the moment. Could you explain how it could be used?

@Yogi thanks but I don’t see how to get those rather specific color changes, or rather, I can’t see how it’s much simpler to use progress bar.

To get the correct color on stopping the animation partway I think the simplest method is a couple of lines of Javascript. Is this acceptable (I imagine you'll be using JS to communicate the % anyway).

@A Haworth Yes I think I'll just use JS

Make the animation paused then use a negative delay.
animation: load 5s forwards -2.5s paused linear;

This will stop the animation at 50% since 2.5/5 = .5 = 50%
Adjust between 0s and -5s to get between 0% and 100%


.color-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.Loading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loading:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  animation: load 5s forwards -2.5s paused linear;
}

@keyframes load {
  0.0% {
    width: 0.0%;
    background: #94e02d;
  }
  2.04% {
    width: 2.04%;
    background: #96e02c;
  }
  4.08% {
    width: 4.08%;
    background: #98e12b;
  }
  6.12% {
    width: 6.12%;
    background: #9ae12a;
  }
  8.16% {
    width: 8.16%;
    background: #9ce229;
  }
  10.2% {
    width: 10.2%;
    background: #9ee328;
  }
  12.24% {
    width: 12.24%;
    background: #a1e327;
  }
  14.29% {
    width: 14.29%;
    background: #a3e426;
  }
  16.33% {
    width: 16.33%;
    background: #a5e525;
  }
  18.37% {
    width: 18.37%;
    background: #a7e524;
  }
  20.41% {
    width: 20.41%;
    background: #a9e623;
  }
  22.45% {
    width: 22.45%;
    background: #ace622;
  }
  24.49% {
    width: 24.49%;
    background: #aee721;
  }
  26.53% {
    width: 26.53%;
    background: #b0e821;
  }
  28.57% {
    width: 28.57%;
    background: #b2e820;
  }
  30.61% {
    width: 30.61%;
    background: #b4e91f;
  }
  32.65% {
    width: 32.65%;
    background: #b6ea1e;
  }
  34.69% {
    width: 34.69%;
    background: #b9ea1d;
  }
  36.73% {
    width: 36.73%;
    background: #bbeb1c;
  }
  38.78% {
    width: 38.78%;
    background: #bdec1b;
  }
  40.82% {
    width: 40.82%;
    background: #bfec1a;
  }
  42.86% {
    width: 42.86%;
    background: #c1ed19;
  }
  44.9% {
    width: 44.9%;
    background: #c4ed18;
  }
  46.94% {
    width: 46.94%;
    background: #c6ee17;
  }
  48.98% {
    width: 48.98%;
    background: #c8ef16;
  }
  51.02% {
    width: 51.02%;
    background: #caef16;
  }
  53.06% {
    width: 53.06%;
    background: #ccf015;
  }
  55.1% {
    width: 55.1%;
    background: #cef114;
  }
  57.14% {
    width: 57.14%;
    background: #d1f113;
  }
  59.18% {
    width: 59.18%;
    background: #d3f212;
  }
  61.22% {
    width: 61.22%;
    background: #d5f211;
  }
  63.27% {
    width: 63.27%;
    background: #d7f310;
  }
  65.31% {
    width: 65.31%;
    background: #d9f40f;
  }
  67.35% {
    width: 67.35%;
    background: #dcf40e;
  }
  69.39% {
    width: 69.39%;
    background: #def50d;
  }
  71.43% {
    width: 71.43%;
    background: #e0f60c;
  }
  73.47% {
    width: 73.47%;
    background: #e2f60b;
  }
  75.51% {
    width: 75.51%;
    background: #e4f70b;
  }
  77.55% {
    width: 77.55%;
    background: #e6f80a;
  }
  79.59% {
    width: 79.59%;
    background: #e9f809;
  }
  81.63% {
    width: 81.63%;
    background: #ebf908;
  }
  83.67% {
    width: 83.67%;
    background: #edf907;
  }
  85.71% {
    width: 85.71%;
    background: #effa06;
  }
  87.76% {
    width: 87.76%;
    background: #f1fb05;
  }
  89.8% {
    width: 89.8%;
    background: #f4fb04;
  }
  91.84% {
    width: 91.84%;
    background: #f6fc03;
  }
  93.88% {
    width: 93.88%;
    background: #f8fd02;
  }
  95.92% {
    width: 95.92%;
    background: #fafd01;
  }
  97.96% {
    width: 97.96%;
    background: #fcfe00;
  }
  100.0% {
    width: 100.0%;
    background: #ffff00;
  }
}
<div class="color-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="Loading"></div>
  </div>
</div>




This is a nice way of getting the end result, but it means there is no animation.
